# Sodium azide to Nitrogen ratio in airbags

Tags: stoichiometry

I've been given this question and I don't know how to solve it.

> Airbags are designed to protect the occupants of a car during a collision. They use the decomposition of sodium azide, $\ce{NaN3}$. Three chemical reactions occur rapidly after impact and produce nitrogen gas ($\ce{N2}$) to fill the airbag.
>
> The equations summarise the overall process that takes place.
>
> 1. $\ce{2 NaN3 -> 2 Na + 3 N_2}$
> 2. $\ce{10 Na + 2 KNO3 -> K2O + 5 Na2O + N2}$
> 3. $\ce{K2O + Na2O + 2 SiO2 -> K2O3Si + Na2O3Si}$
>
> What is the ratio between the number of sodium azide ($\ce{NaN3}$) molecules used and the number of nitrogen ($\ce{N2}$) molecules produced in the overall process?

I initially just used the first equation to get a ratio of 2:3, but obviously that's not right. I have no clue where to start. How do you do this? (How this can be considered a Year 10 question baffles me)

Comment: It baffles me also. You need also to consider the second equation, which produces N2 gas as well. The first equation generates Na, and this is consumed in the second equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an excess of $\ce{KNO3}$, the ratio of $\ce{NaN3}$ consumed to $\ce{N2}$ produced would be 5:8.

Let's renormalize the first two equations, dividing the first through by 2, and the second through by 10.  By doing this we can see, directly, that in the overall reaction, 3/2 + 1/10 = 8/5 = 1.6 molecules of $\ce{N_2}$ are produced for every molecule of  $\ce{NaN3}$ consumed.  If you prefer an integer ratio, it's 1:(8/5) = 5:8.

> 1. $\ce{NaN3 -> Na + 3/2 N_2}$
> 2. $\ce{Na + 1/5 KNO3 -> 1/10K2O + 1/2 Na2O + 1/10 N2}$

Answer (score -3):

The initial ratio 2:3 is correct. $\ce{2NaN3 = 2 Na}$ molecules as well as $\ce{6 N}$ molecules. The products of the reaction, $\ce{2Na}$ is equal to two $\ce{Na}$ molecules and $\ce{3N2}$ is equal to $\ce{6 N}$ molecules. So as you can see the equation is perfectly balanced. Hope this helps.